# Automatically launch a software, download data and save to folder (local software)

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, command

Apologies for the vagueness of the question, but I am mainly looking for resources of how to learn to do the following task. I have some software on my computer and would like to automate the following tasks (since it occurs daily):

1. Launch the program
2. Click some buttons
3. Save the new data file to a specific folder

The only thing I have come across is the `subprocess` module in python and `start` for the command line to launch the program. However, I am at a loss for how to get my computer to click certain buttons (using a script) once the software is open. Any ideas or recommendations for where I can learn more about this is greatly appreciated. Once I have the script I know how to schedule the task to occur everyday.  Thanks!

I am using Windows and there is no API for the software.

Comment: What operating system are you running? Is there an API for the software you are working with? "Clicking some buttons" is a poor way to automate something, you would need an auto-hotkey script or something, but if there is an API, or you can emulate the program's function in some way from a script, it would be better. Need more info to answer.

Comment: @AlexEshoo, Apologies, I completely forgot some crucial information. I edited above. I am using Windows and there is no API to easily access the data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: "looking for resources" is an off topic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you specify what OS you are using or some other details but considering the few details given, you can use a scripting language that can run GUI applications, here are a few examples:

1.Windows:

AutoHotKey:
https://autohotkey.com/

AutoIt:
https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

2.Linux:

xdotool: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

3.Mac:

Automator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_macOS_components#Automator

Comment: Keep in mind that automating tasks with auto-hotkey is hacky at best. Better to see if you can emulate the function of the program in the background without using the GUI.

Comment: Can't say I disagree, but he wants to "run some software" and "click some buttons", autohotkey certainly can do that.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is a poor way to get the data (and a bad question), but I cannot access the data without the GUI and needed ideas.

Comment: @roarkz no worries, I hope you find your way around that, AHK is a very powerful tool for certain tools that have no command line support whatsoever.